# Converting server operation system Windows XP to Ubuntu

Tags: zend-framework, mongodb, windows-xp, development-environment, ubuntu-11.04

Previously I had some problem that cannot run a PHP project previously made in Windows XP to Ubuntu server with plain PHP.

If I start working on a new project with Zend Framework (PHP) in Windows XP, does it cause some problem porting to ubuntu environment(Also mongodb in Windows to Ubuntu)?
Problems were different file format system, file privilege, case-sensitive(Ubuntu) or insensitive(Windows) issues.

I believe the Framework will take care of miscellaneous environment differences between those two operating systems.
If not, should I start my project on Ubuntu?

If developing on Ubuntu is the best choice, using FTP is the best way to update code?
What about running Zend console through "zf" commands?

I need some suggestion and advice on Zend Framework Development Environments and Know-Hows.

Comment: I use zend project both windows and Linux environment. But i used MySQL and PostgreSQL. would you mention what are the problems did you have?

Comment: Yeah. I should have mentioned that :) I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not genes in zend framework. But I use zend project in both Windows and Linux environment.

File formatting is not problem in both OS. Because php, phtml, ini etc.. file are working in both system.

In linux you should give read permission to web user for your project.